# Problem with left positioning of menu sidebar doesn't work

Tags: css

Good evening everyone, I am creating my first basic web application and I have problems with the frontend, I am not very good with this topic.
I have a problem with my css html code.
I have 2 menus a sidebar and a navbar I want to get my menu (sidebar) to be positioned on the left side but I can't get close to that effect.
I leave a photo so you can see how I want the menu to look

[image]

```js
    $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
    });
```

```css
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: black;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: black;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: blue;
}




#RenderBody {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;

    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

i.fas,
i.fab {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    font-size:25px;
}

a:hover {
    color: violet;
}



.fa-fish {
    color: red;
}

.fa-frog {
    color: red;
}

.fa-user-ninja.vanished {
    opacity: 0.0;
}

.fa-facebook {
    color: rgb(59, 91, 152);
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {


}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: -250px;
    }

    #sidebar .sidebar-header {
        padding: 20px;
        background: #6d7fcc;
    }

    #sidebar ul.components {
        padding: 20px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
    }

    #sidebar ul p {
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        display: block;
    }

        #sidebar ul li a:hover {
            color: #7386D5;
            background: #fff;
        }

    #sidebar ul li.active > a,
    a[aria-expanded="true"] {
        color: #fff;
        background: #6d7fcc;
    }

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

    ul.CTAs a {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 0.9em !important;
        display: block;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

a.download {
    background: #fff;
    color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
    background: #6d7fcc !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - test</title>

    <environment include="Development">
        <!-- <Libreria Font Awesome> -->
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/55c228f8f9.js"></script>

        <!-- <Libreria TadaTable> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
        <!-- <Libreria Boostrap> -->
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <!-- Sidebar  -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>Bootstrap Sidebar</h3>
            </div>

            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <p>Dummy Heading</p>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Pages</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/files/sidebar.zip" class="download">Download source</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar" class="article">Back to article</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- Sidebar  -->
        <!--Navbar-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" id="TopNavBar">
            <div class="container">
                <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                    <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                    <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Inicio</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="TopUL">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a href="/Home/About" class="nav-link">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a href="/Home/Contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!--/.Navbar-->

        <div class="container">
            <div class="arrow">
                <div id="RenderBody">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">

<h1> This is the Index </h1>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="py-5">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <form class="form-inline"></form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 col-md-1 align-self-center">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-3x"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 col-md-1 align-self-center">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fab fa-twitter-square fa-3x"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 col-md-1 align-self-center">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-3x"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 mt-3 text-center">
                            <p>© Copyright 2019  - All rights reserved.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <environment include="Development">
            <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <!-- <Libreria TadaTable>-->
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
            <!-- </Libreria TadaTable>-->
            <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        </environment>
        <environment exclude="Development">
            <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                    crossorigin="anonymous"
                    integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT">
            </script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                    crossorigin="anonymous"
                    integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd">
            </script>
            <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        </environment>

        @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
        </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want it to fixed in the left side? even when scrolling ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `position` value to `fiexed` or `absolute` and show/hide the menu by changing `left` value

```js
$('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
        $("body").toggleClass('show-menu'); // Toggle the body margin
    });
```

```css
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: black;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: black;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: blue;
}




#RenderBody {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;

    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

i.fas,
i.fab {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    font-size:25px;
}

a:hover {
    color: violet;
}



.fa-fish {
    color: red;
}

.fa-frog {
    color: red;
}

.fa-user-ninja.vanished {
    opacity: 0.0;
}

.fa-facebook {
    color: rgb(59, 91, 152);
}


/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

.wrapper {


}
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: margin-left .3s;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
body.show-menu{
  margin-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    /*======== Edit ========*/
    position: fixed; /* Or you can make it 'absolute' if you don't want it to be fiexed */ 
    top: 0px; /* For the header */
    height: 100%;
    left: -250px;
    z-index: 10;
}

    #sidebar.active {
        left: 0px;
    }

    #sidebar .sidebar-header {
        padding: 20px;
        background: #6d7fcc;
    }

    #sidebar ul.components {
        padding: 20px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
    }

    #sidebar ul p {
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        display: block;
    }

        #sidebar ul li a:hover {
            color: #7386D5;
            background: #fff;
        }

    #sidebar ul li.active > a,
    a[aria-expanded="true"] {
        color: #fff;
        background: #6d7fcc;
    }

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

    ul.CTAs a {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 0.9em !important;
        display: block;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

a.download {
    background: #fff;
    color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
    background: #6d7fcc !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - test</title>

    <environment include="Development">
        <!-- <Libreria Font Awesome> -->
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/55c228f8f9.js"></script>

        <!-- <Libreria TadaTable> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
        <!-- <Libreria Boostrap> -->
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <!-- Sidebar  -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>Bootstrap Sidebar</h3>
            </div>

            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <p>Dummy Heading</p>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Pages</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/files/sidebar.zip" class="download">Download source</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar" class="article">Back to article</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- Sidebar  -->
        <!--Navbar-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" id="TopNavBar">
            <div class="container">
                <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
                    <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                    <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Inicio</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="TopUL">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a href="/Home/About" class="nav-link">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a href="/Home/Contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!--/.Navbar-->

        <div class="container">
            <div class="arrow">
                <div id="RenderBody">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">

<h1> This is the Index </h1>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="py-5">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <form class="form-inline"></form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 col-md-1 align-self-center">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-3x"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 col-md-1 align-self-center">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fab fa-twitter-square fa-3x"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 col-md-1 align-self-center">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-3x"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 mt-3 text-center">
                            <p>© Copyright 2019  - All rights reserved.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <environment include="Development">
            <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <!-- <Libreria TadaTable>-->
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
            <!-- </Libreria TadaTable>-->
            <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        </environment>
        <environment exclude="Development">
            <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                    crossorigin="anonymous"
                    integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT">
            </script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                    crossorigin="anonymous"
                    integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd">
            </script>
            <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        </environment>

        @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
        </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to have this same effect, that the menu is coupled to the div, when the menu is hidden that the web content expands
https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/sidebar/index.html

Comment: Move the body to right by using `margin-left`, I edited the code.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want that first block of `<nav> ... </nav>` (sidebar) underneath your second `<nav> ... </nav>` (navbar)

Comment: I want to have this same effect, that the menu is coupled to the div, when the menu is hidden that the web content expands
https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/sidebar/index.html